# ReactJs ERROR whille making onInputChange

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**Please HELP me and see the pictures I added.**

It's saying **MISSING SEMI-COLONE**. After I added the semi-colon it says **onInputChange** not Found.

Please help me with this

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebpBX.png)

[After adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLyys.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think constructor keywork only will work in class based component, try making class based component like class App extends React.component

Comment: Thank you. I research your answer and I found a way. Your answer is really helpful.
Now I understand About the

"function App" and "class App extends Component"